# How to replace a text with a keyword?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Hello I'm creating a chat app and I was tryin to make textarea to accept svg files, but it only accepts the code, so I made it taking the code to the text area. The problem is that the text of the svg files(made them php) is huge. How can I cover/replace them to textarea only with a word? And this I can use it only once, how can I use it multiple times without pressing F5 everytime that I want to add an emoji? Here is the code for the chat, Thank you!

```
    <textarea id="comment" style="width: 280px; margin-top: 10px; box- 
     shadow: inset 0 -15px 35px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); height: 40px; 
    overflow: auto;">
    </textarea>

          <center><p class="emoticonsTitle">Emojis</p></center>
            <div class="emojis">
              <ul>
                  <li><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="test()"><img 
                src="emoticons/cloudda3.svg" 
               style="width:28px;height:28px;"/></a></li>
                  <li><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="test2()"><img 
  src="emoticons/cloudnigh3.svg" style="width:28px;height:28px;"/></a></li>
                  <li><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="test3()"><img 
  src="emoticons/cloudy.svg" style="width:28px;height:28px;"/></a></li>
                  <li><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="test4()"><img 
  src="emoticons/cloudy-day-1.svg" style="width:28px;height:28px;"/></a> 
  </li>
                  <li><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="test5()"><img 
  src="emoticons/cloudy-day-2.svg" style="width:28px;height:28px;" /></a> 
  </li>
                  <li><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="test6()"><img 
                  src="emoticons/cloudy-night-1.svg" 
                  style="width:28px;height:28px;" /></a></li>
                  <li><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="test7()"><img 
                  src="emoticons/cloudy-night-2.svg" 
                  style="width:28px;height:28px;" /></a></li>
                  <li><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="test8()"><img 
                  src="emoticons/night.svg" style="width:28px;height:28px;" 
                   /></a></li>
                  <li><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="test9()"><img 
                  src="emoticons/rainy-1.svg" 
                  style="width:28px;height:28px;" /></a></li>
                  <li><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="test10()"><img 
                  src="emoticons/rainy-2.svg" 
                   style="width:28px;height:28px;" /></a></li>
                  <li><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="test11()"><img 
                  src="emoticons/rainy-3.svg" 
                  style="width:28px;height:28px;" /></a></li>
                  <li><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="test12()"><img 
                  src="emoticons/rainy-4.svg" 
                  style="width:28px;height:28px;" /></a></li>
                  <li><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="test13()"><img 
                  src="emoticons/rainy-5.svg" 
                  style="width:28px;height:28px;" /></a></li>
                  <li><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="test14()"><img 
                   src="emoticons/rainy-6.svg" 
                  style="width:28px;height:28px;" /></a></li>
                  <li><a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="test15()"><img 
                   src="emoticons/rainy-7.svg" 
                  style="width:28px;height:28px;" /></a></li>
                  </ul>



          <script type="text/javascript">
          function test(){
              $.ajax({url:"cloudda3.php",success:function(result){
              $("#comment").text(result);
            }})
           }

          function test2(){
              $.ajax({url:"cloudnigh3.php",success:function(result){
              $("#comment").text(result);
            }})
           }

          function test3(){
              $.ajax({url:"cloudy.php",success:function(result){
              $("#comment").text(result);
            }})
           }

          function test4(){
              $.ajax({url:"cloudy-day-1.php",success:function(result){
              $("#comment").text(result);
            }})
           }

          function test5(){
              $.ajax({url:"cloudy-day-2.php",success:function(result){
              $("#comment").text(result);
            }})
           }

          function test6(){
              $.ajax({url:"cloudy-night-1.php",success:function(result){
              $("#comment").text(result);
            }})
           }

          function test7(){
              $.ajax({url:"cloudy-night-2.php",success:function(result){
              $("#comment").text(result);
            }})
           }

          function test8(){
              $.ajax({url:"night.php",success:function(result){
              $("#comment").text(result);
            }})
           }

          function test9(){
              $.ajax({url:"rainy-1.php",success:function(result){
              $("#comment").text(result);
            }})
           }

          function test10(){
              $.ajax({url:"rainy-2.php",success:function(result){
              $("#comment").text(result);
            }})
           }

          function test11(){
              $.ajax({url:"rainy-3.php",success:function(result){
              $("#comment").text(result);
            }})
           }

          function test12(){
              $.ajax({url:"rainy-4.php",success:function(result){
              $("#comment").text(result);
            }})
           }

          function test13(){
              $.ajax({url:"rainy-5.php",success:function(result){
              $("#comment").text(result);
            }})
           }

          function test14(){
              $.ajax({url:"rainy-6.php",success:function(result){
              $("#comment").text(result);
            }})
           }

          function test15(){
              $.ajax({url:"rainy-7.php",success:function(result){
              $("#comment").text(result);
            }})
           }

          </script>

           </div><!--Emojis-->
           <br>
           <br>
      <input type="text" style="display:none;" id="username" value="<?php 
      echo 
      $_SESSION['user']['username']; ?>">
          <button id="btn" name="btn" type="submit" onclick="post();" 
         style="top: 30px; cursor: pointer; color: #000; font-size: 24px; 
         height: 40px; border:none; font-weight: bold; box-shadow: inset 0 
        -15px 35px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);">Αποστολή
          </button>

   </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drac WarThorn,

I think you should using val() instead of text() to push new value for TextArea

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          function test(){
              $.ajax({url:"cloudda3.php",success:function(result){
              $("#comment").val(result);
            }})
           }

          function test2(){
              $.ajax({url:"cloudnigh3.php",success:function(result){
              $("#comment").val(result);
            }})
           }

          function test3(){
              $.ajax({url:"cloudy.php",success:function(result){
              $("#comment").val(result);
            }})
           }

          function test4(){
              $.ajax({url:"cloudy-day-1.php",success:function(result){
              $("#comment").val(result);
            }})
           }

          function test5(){
              $.ajax({url:"cloudy-day-2.php",success:function(result){
              $("#comment").val(result);
            }})
           }

          function test6(){
              $.ajax({url:"cloudy-night-1.php",success:function(result){
              $("#comment").val(result);
            }})
           }

          function test7(){
              $.ajax({url:"cloudy-night-2.php",success:function(result){
              $("#comment").val(result);
            }})
           }

          function test8(){
              $.ajax({url:"night.php",success:function(result){
              $("#comment").val(result);
            }})
           }

          function test9(){
              $.ajax({url:"rainy-1.php",success:function(result){
              $("#comment").val(result);
            }})
           }

          function test10(){
              $.ajax({url:"rainy-2.php",success:function(result){
              $("#comment").val(result);
            }})
           }

          function test11(){
              $.ajax({url:"rainy-3.php",success:function(result){
              $("#comment").val(result);
            }})
           }

          function test12(){
              $.ajax({url:"rainy-4.php",success:function(result){
              $("#comment").val(result);
            }})
           }

          function test13(){
              $.ajax({url:"rainy-5.php",success:function(result){
              $("#comment").val(result);
            }})
           }

          function test14(){
              $.ajax({url:"rainy-6.php",success:function(result){
              $("#comment").val(result);
            }})
           }

          function test15(){
              $.ajax({url:"rainy-7.php",success:function(result){
              $("#comment").val(result);
            }})
           }

          </script>
```

Comment: Thanks that help, but I want you know, to minimize the text or the val at the textarea, so I can put multiple emojis too, like this :) :) :). With val I can call them anytime thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use contenteditable attribute for that purpose

```
There is an example

https://codepen.io/meddjelaili/pen/KrZYRK
```